# Identify a file uniquely on the sdcard

Tags: android, file, android-sdcard

Is there a way to uniquely identify a file on the **sdcard** apart from the file's absolute path? The File class does have an inherited method `hashCode()`, but I am not sure if that's fine.

Comment: Hashcode is not guaranteed to be unique but according to the documentation it is used to compare two files when checking for equality. What are you wanting to use it for?

Answer (score 0):

The file path should be unique enough for pretty much all purposes.

I'm sure the `hashCode()` is based on the internal representation and might change.

Answer (score 0):

You can always check the **java** source code and see what the `hashCode()` function is doing. From the [File class source code](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/io/File.java.html):

- **hashCode()**:

> Computes a hash code for this abstract pathname.  Because equality of
>   abstract pathnames is inherently system-dependent, so is the computation
>   of their hash codes.  On UNIX systems, the hash code of an abstract
>   pathname is equal to the exclusive or of the hash code
>   of its pathname string and the decimal value
>   1234321. On Microsoft Windows systems, the hash
>   code is equal to the exclusive or of the hash code of
>   its pathname string converted to lower case and the decimal
>   value 1234321.  Locale is not taken into account on
>   lowercasing the pathname string.
>   
>   As you can see the `hashCode()` function is creating the hash base on the pathname, so you can use it to compare 2 files instead of using `getAbsolutePath()`.